# Php unit test case always fails

Tags: zend-framework2, phpunit

The written unit test case in PHPUnit with Zend always returns 404 error. What's wrong in my code.

```
use Zend\Test\PHPUnit\Controller\AbstractHttpControllerTestCase;

class IndexControllerTest extends AbstractHttpControllerTestCase
{    
    protected $traceError = TRUE;

    public function setUp()
    {
        $this->setApplicationConfig(
            include 'F:/xampp/htdocs/PHPUnitDemo/src/config/application.config.php'
        );
        parent::setUp();
    }

    public function testIndexActionCanBeAccessed()
    {
        $this->dispatch('/crg/index/index');
        $this->assertResponseStatusCode(200);
        $this->assertModuleName('Crg');
        $this->assertControllerName('IndexController::class');
        $this->assertControllerClass('IndexController');
        $this->assertMatchedRouteName('crg');
    }
}
```

> PHPUnit 4.8.36 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.
>
> F
>
> Time: 3.07 seconds, Memory: 10.25MB
>
> There was 1 failure:
>
> 1) test\Controller\IndexControllerTest::testIndexActionCanBeAccessed
>   Failed asserting response code "200", actual status code is "500"
>
> F:\xampp\htdocs\PHPUnitDemo\src\vendor\ZF2\library\Zend\Test\PHPUnit\Controller\AbstractControllerTestCase.php:412
>   F:\xampp\htdocs\PHPUnitDemo\src\module\Crg\test\CrgTest\Controller\IndexControllerTest.php:22
>
> FAILURES!
>   Tests: 1, Assertions: 0, Failures: 1.

Comment: Your version of phpunit is very oudated. I suggest updating to at least a 7.x version but 8.x if possible. Also your test is not returning a 404, but a 500. Which means something went wrong on the server side. Check the logs there to see what happened.

Comment: Thank for your reply. I am using Zend Framework 2, is it feasible to use PHPUnit version 7 or 8 with this.

Comment: I have checked logs, error is because I am not logged in to the application when running the test case using the command line. Is there any way to logged in while running the test case through the command line?